# Audio lags when headphones are plugged in

Tags: laptop, audio, headphones, hp-pavilion

I have a laptop HP PAVILION dv6-3126er with Windows 7 Home Edition installed and whenever i plug in any headphone and trying to play some music it randomly lags. It may play okay a few seconds and than it is kind of jamming and lagging...It doesn't happen with the speakers of the laptop himself. This happens even when I'm not touching the TRS connector (because when i touch it or rotate it a bit the sound is lagging too).
What can i do?

Comment: Does the CPU appear extra busy once the headphones are inserted?  Have you checked your sound driver settings (for things like delays, sound processing, and to ensure it knows what device type is plugged in)?  Have you tried reinstalling your sound drivers?

Comment: The CPU is not busy at all and I've already tried to reinstall the drivers. Still the same. As i said this is only happens with headphones. The sound is ok when it from the speakers of the laptop.